# Laravel: Ajax dynamic dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

when I select particular country in select box then in state select box must be filled with state data of selected country and so on. But after selecting the country(parent select box), the province(child) still empty. The event(in browser console) is passing the selected value and then gives an error(see result).

I tried this code with different laravel versions: 5.4 - 5.7. I'm not really good with AJAX.

CountryController.php

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use IlluminateHttpRequest;
use IlluminateSupportFacadesInput;

use App\Provinces;
use App\Regencies;
use App\Districts;
use App\Villages;


class CountryController extends Controller
{
public function provinces(){
  $provinces = Provinces::all();
  return view('country.index', compact('provinces'));
}

public function regencies(){
  $provinces_id = Input::get('province_id');
  $regencies = Regencies::where('province_id', '=', $provinces_id)->get();
  return response()->json($regencies);
}

public function districts(){
  $regencies_id = Input::get('regencies_id');
  $districts = Districts::where('regency_id', '=', $regencies_id)->get();
  return response()->json($districts);
}

public function villages(){
  $districts_id = Input::get('districts_id');
  $villages = Villages::where('district_id', '=', $districts_id)->get();
  return response()->json($villages);
 }
}
```

---

MODELS

---

District:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Districts extends Model
{
protected $table = 'districts';
}
```

Provinces :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Provinces extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'provinces';
}

Regencies:

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Regencies extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'regencies';
}

Villages:

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Villages extends Model
{
protected $table = 'villages';
}
```

---

VIEW: index.blade.php

---

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Your Provinces</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="provinces" id="provinces">
          <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Provinces ===</option>
            @foreach ($provinces as $key => $value)
              <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Your Regencies</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="regencies" id="regencies">
          <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Regencies ===</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Your Districts</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="districts" id="districts">
          <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Districts ===</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Your Villages</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="villages" id="villages">
          <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Villages ===</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#provinces').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var province_id = e.target.value;
    $.get('/json-regencies?province_id=' + province_id,function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#regencies').empty();
      $('#regencies').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Regencies ===</option>');

      $('#districts').empty();
      $('#districts').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Districts ===</option>');

      $('#villages').empty();
      $('#villages').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Villages ===</option>');

      $.each(data, function(index, regenciesObj){
        $('#regencies').append('<option value="'+ regenciesObj.id +'">'+ regenciesObj.name +'</option>');
      })
    });
  });

  $('#regencies').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var regencies_id = e.target.value;
    $.get('/json-districts?regencies_id=' + regencies_id,function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#districts').empty();
      $('#districts').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Districts ===</option>');

      $.each(data, function(index, districtsObj){
        $('#districts').append('<option value="'+ districtsObj.id +'">'+ districtsObj.name +'</option>');
      })
    });
  });

  $('#districts').on('change', function(e){
    // console.log(e);
    var districts_id = e.target.value;
    $.get('/json-village?districts_id=' + districts_id,function(data) {
      // console.log(data);
      $('#villages').empty();
      $('#villages').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select Villages ===</option>');

      $.each(data, function(index, villagesObj){
        $('#villages').append('<option value="'+ villagesObj.id +'">'+ villagesObj.name +'</option>');
      })
    });
  });


</script>
```

ROUTE:

---

```
Route::get('/indonesia','CountryController@provinces');

Route::get('/json-regencies','CountryController@regencies');

Route::get('/json-districts', 'CountryController@districts');

Route::get('/json-village', 'CountryController@villages');
```

Result:

---

[Please see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTNpu.png)

Comment: The ajax looks good, What is the error?

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero, please see the error on the link above. After selecting the country(parent select box), the province(child) still empty. It doesn't pass data to the child select box. Any idea?

Comment: I have watched the error not. That is an error in server side. Please go to the tab network (insetead console) of Chrome and preview the response of that call. Sure there is a clue. Or paste here.

Comment: Your are using Input Facades.... where is it declared? Input::get('province_id');

Comment: I dont' know how I missed it. I imported the input facade and works fine. Also used request in each method and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you imported Input facades if you're going to use the first option:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

public function regencies(Request $request){
  $provinces_id = $request->province_id;
  $regencies = Regencies::where('province_id', '=', $provinces_id)->get();
  return response()->json($regencies);
}
```

OR

Import HTTP request and use the second option:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function regencies(Request $request){
  $provinces_id = $request->province_id;
  $regencies = Regencies::where('province_id', '=', $provinces_id)->get();
  return response()->json($regencies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please declare Input Facade to use it in your controller.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)